# Understanding 3 parameters in MySQL workbench Code Editor settings

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

What do the following three settings mean in MySQL Workbench?

[image]

These three parameters are mentioned briefly on the [General Editor Settings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-preferences-general-editors.html), but I'm wondering what might be an example of their usage. For example:

> SQL Identifiers are Case Sensitive: Enabled by default. Whether to treat identifiers separately if their names differ only in letter case.

Does this mean, for example that:

```
SELECT * from main_iteminstance
```

is different from:

```
SELECT * FROM main_iteminstance
```

The answer is no when I tried both, but isn't `FROM` a sql identifier, so what would this setting mean exactly?

Comment: @Shadow -- so in the above, 'identifiers' = table names?

Comment: Pls read the linked mysql manual page in the accespted answer of the identifier duplicate.

Comment: @Shadow just to clarify, this one you mean? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html